# ASP.NET WebAPI and Angular integration. Collection not found

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, get

first of all, sorry for my English.
I am trying to integrate an asp.net web api with Angular. At the moment I have only implemented the get method and when I call it in Angular, I always get 404 error. Does anyone know how to fix?

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
    public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Servizi e configurazione dell'API Web
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Route dell'API Web
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
  
    }
}
```

**Products.cs**

```
    public class Product {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public int qta { get; set; }

    public List<Product> GetAll() {
        List<Product> productsList = new List<Product>() {
            new Product { id = "id1", name = "prodotto1", description = "descrizione 1", price = 123.42, qta = 4 },
            new Product { id = "id2", name = "prodotto2", description = "descrizione 2", price = 13.42, qta = 4 },
            new Product { id = "id3", name = "prodotto3", description = "descrizione 3", price = 12.45, qta = 2 },
            new Product { id = "id4", name = "prodotto4", description = "descrizione 4", price = 23, qta = 7 },
            new Product { id = "id5", name = "prodotto5", description = "descrizione 5", price = 63.99, qta = 5 }
        };
        return productsList;
    }

    public Product GetProduct(string id) {
        return GetAll().Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

**ProductController.cs**

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get() {
        return new Product().GetAll();
    }
}
```

**WebApiService.ts**

```
@Injectable({


 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebapiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getValue() {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:44342/api/Product');
  }
}
```

**WebApiTestComponent**

```
  export class WebApiTestComponent implements OnInit {
  value: any[] = [];

  constructor(public webApi: WebapiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.webApi.getValue().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.value = data;
    });
  }
```

That is the error:
[image: Error message]

Comment: If I could make a suggestion. Debugging http verbs can be tricky at the best of times. Best to avoid Angular at this stage and use a tool like postman to simulate the http calls. Once you have the api working as expected, then wire up the angular call.

Comment: Are you using .net Core for your backend, then all the data serialisation issues and response codes can be handled for you by inheriting ControllerBase in your controller and decorating the  class with [ApiController]. Then you'll have access to IActionResult  or ActionResult<T> as your return object.

Comment: @DarrenStreet I'm not using .net core. It is an ASP.NET Web Application with Web API template. I tried to use Postman and it works well. I am able to get all the products in JSON format.

Comment: The thing is if you use IActionResult as your return type, it will serialise your custom class automatically.

Comment: this is an excellent tut to get you started https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @DarrenStreet I found the problem. The code is correct. The problem is within the Angular project. In this project I use InMemoryWebApi in another component and the two things conflict. Do you have any ideas on how to use both? Anyway thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Oh right. I see. I don't think you can use both. The inMemoryApi hijacks the route to simulate a real API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The code is correct. The problem is within the Angular project. In this project I use InMemoryWebApi in another component and the two things confilct. So, to solve the problem, I added in the AppModule passThruUnknownUrl option.

```
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(AppData, {delay: 1000, passThruUnknownUrl: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `AppData`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AppDataService implements InMemoryDbService{

  constructor() { }
  createDb(){

  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).